# How encrypt and verify files digital signatures with no code?

Tags: encryption, lets-encrypt, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying organize a system of digital signature encryption and verification for my digital art being sold on a Wordpress website, without having to use code for this whole process. I am attempting to make this process straight forward and accessible for the average person with no code skills, so we can all understand and verify our ownership in simple terms, Hopefully. Is this possible?

Found this answers in a question similar to mine here:

“
1 Digest the file with a hashing algorithm like SHA-256. Creates a summary of a few bytes "hash"

2 Sign the hash using the RSA private key. This is called the "signature"

3 Send the file and the signature to a third party. They can verify the signature using the public key. If signature match then you can ensure the identity of the sender of the message and that has not been altered.
“

The first step is easy, there are plenty of softwares that we can download to produce this hash from a file just like using code it seems.

Now from the second step forward I am stuck. I am starting to understand the protocols now, but don’t know how to apply it… I’ve generated a private and public key using bitaddrres.org, but wasn’t able to figure out a way to make the encryption and decryption of the hash sequence without having to use code.

Do you see an easy solution for this? Perhaps a software people in my network could download, any help at this point would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Question should be asked in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You'll need to look into signature generation and verification. The main algorithms used currently are RSA (in PKCS#1 variety and PSS) and ECDSA. Both include hashing normally, you just need to *configure* the right hash. The main trick is to get the other party to trust your public key. For that you can study certificates (PKIX). The rest is not that simple either, as **anybody** can sign **anything**. So you might want to use **recognized** signatures used for **non-repudiation** and time stamping. Possibly a third party acting as a notary.

Comment: For the EU, for instance, there is the notion of [*qualified electronic signatures*](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/wikis/display/DIGITAL/eSignature+FAQ). It is all great to sign things, but if nobody recognizes the validity of your signature, it isn't that much use. I've just posted this because I'm a bit afraid of the reaction in the [crypto.se] site, and I can know cause I'm currently moderator there. I'd say "understand and verify our ownership in simple terms, Hopefully. Is this possible?": the answer is simply **no** (possible yes, simple no).